# String Values not showing in listview using base adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I am passing value as string from an activity through intent to this Page Activity and adding it to an arraylist and setting that list to an list view using base adapter.But unfortunately its the values are not showing in listview.
And I am not able to figure out how to set that value to the textview present in PagesAdapter.java.

Please help me guys.

Pages.java

```
  public class Pages extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = null;

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private PagesAdapter pageadapter;
    private String androidOS;
    private String device_uuid;
    private String contributor_id;
    public String tocName;
    public String categoryName;
    private SessionManager session;
    private String first_Page;
    private String last_Page;
    private String current_Page;
    private String firstPage;
    private String lastPage;
    private String currentPage;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    private String page;
    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pages);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CONTENT");
        name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
        firstPage = pref.getString("firstpage",null);
        lastPage = pref.getString("lastpage",null);
        currentPage = pref.getString("currentpage",null);
        contributor_id = pref.getString("contributor_id",null);
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);
        //getData();

//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        device_uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        list.add(name);
        pageadapter = new PagesAdapter(Pages.this, list);
                        listView.setAdapter(pageadapter);
     }
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Pages.this, RecordComposition.class);
        i.putExtra("PAGE",page);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

PagesAdapter.java

```
public class PagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> Pagelist;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public PagesAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> billionairesItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.Pagelist = billionairesItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Pagelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return Pagelist.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_view, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
//        String m = Pagelist.get(position);
        //        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getImage(), imageLoader);
//        name.setText(m.get);
        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set value to the textView :

```
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(Pagelist.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is related to your `list` variable. You are passing it as a `Empty List`, because you are not populating it with `String` values. 
The adapter will scan your list and verify that there is no data to display, so try to put some data inside the list variable and test the `ListView` again.

The second question is easy to resolve, just add these lines inside your getView method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(Pagelist.get(position));
   }
```